# Store the output from multiple commands on a single line in a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to store output of two commands to a file as a single line. However the output stored is on two different lines.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

date > test.log; pwd >> test.log
```

Output:

```
~]# cat test.log

Mon Jan 19 23:37:31 PST 2015
/home/jason
```

How do I make as single line?

Expected output

```
~]# cat test.log

Mon Jan 19 23:37:31 PST 2015    /home/jason
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the `echo` command 'flattens' its arguments into a single line of output.  When the commands each produce a single line of output, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28040174/15168) given by [John Zwinck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4323/john-zwinck) works well — and even avoids using the `pwd` command to generate the current working directory.

If the commands produce multiple lines of output, then his formulation writes multiple lines to the log.  For example, if the commands are:

```
printf "%s\n" line-1 line-2 line-3
printf "%s\n" more-1 more-2 more-3
```

then running:

```
echo "$(printf "%s\n" line-1 line-2 line-3) $(printf "%s\n" more-1 more-2 more-3)" > test.log
```

adds five lines to the output.  Instead, to get the flattening, you need to avoid the quotes (this time — relatively unusually):

```
echo $(printf "%s\n" line-1 line-2 line-3) $(printf "%s\n" more-1 more-2 more-3) > test.log
```

This adds just one line to the output, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo "$(date)    $PWD" > test.log
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have to execute the 2 commands at different instances and still need to append to the same file and on the same line, you can do something like this:

```
AMD$ echo -n "$(date) " > File
AMD$ echo "$(pwd)" >> File
AMD$ cat File
Tue Jan 20 13:27:41 IST 2015 /home/sdlcb/AMD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just make `date` command to output date and another command's output like this in same line:

```
date "+%a, %b %d %T %Z %Y $(pwd)"
Tue, Jan 20 03:12:15 EST 2015 /home/jason
```

`date` command will accept regular date format commands with whatever literal text you want in output.

Comment: That fails if the command isn't `pwd` and does include any `%x` sequences in the output.  Not likely to be a problem with `pwd`.